# Sign in to multiple instagram accounts using php api

Tags: php, mysql, instagram, instagram-api

In my website I need to sign in to instagram using php api. I used this guide an it works well:

"[Login with Instagram using PHP](https://www.codexworld.com/login-with-instagram-using-php/)"

But the problem is with this guide u need to enter username and password each time and it's a hard work for 100 accounts. I have usernames and passwords in a database table (mysql), and I want to create a page that with clicking on "LOGIN":

1- get username and password from database

2- send username and password for verify to instagram

3- get code and save it to database

I can do Part 1 and 3 but I have no idea how to send username and password to instagram api without typing it.

I hop my question is clear:

"Is there anyway to login 100 accounts to instagram and save each (auth_uid and other return data) into database in PHP?"

**UPDATE:**

Let me ask my question in a better way:

as I searched for Instagram API I found out the only way to get access to an account is entering username and password on Instagram page. I want to know if it is possible to enter username and password on my website and then send them to API to verify?

Answer (score -1):

You require Instagram access token.you can get only 20 media of access token owner.

You can visit below link for detail explanation.

https://rudrastyh.com/instagram/get-recent-photos-php.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it is not what I asked, question updated.